# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, postman

I am trying to protect my api routes with a JWT token. I am testing it with Postman. The token is being created successfully and is being shown in postman. But when i am trying to protect the routes, this error comes. This error shows when I try to access the protected routes. Here is the code-
routes-

```
// All imports
import express from "express";

// Controllers import
import controller from "./../../../controllers/index.js";

// JWT check
import { protect } from "../../../middleware/authMiddleware.js";

// Config
const router = express.Router();

// Get all users (auth required)
router.get("/", controller.userController.getAllUsers);

// Get specific user (auth required)
router.get("/:id", controller.userController.getUserById);

// Create new user
router.post("/new", controller.userController.createUser);

// Update existing user (auth required)
router.patch("/:id/update", protect, controller.userController.updateUser);


// Delete user (auth required)
router.get("/:id/delete", protect, controller.userController.deleteUser);


// Logout the user
router.get("/:id/logout", controller.userController.logoutUser);

export default router;
```

middleware file code-

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from "../models/User.js";

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  token = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select('-password');

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error('Not authorized, token failed');
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Not authorized, no token');
  }
});

export { protect };
```

I have tried almsot everything. The packages are also up to date. The token is being created upon login and deleted upon logout.

Comment: I would suspect your sending your JWT token as an authentication header bearer token not as a Cookie, therefore the cookie `jwt` does not exist. Can you please check how the token is being provided in Postman (see Authorziation tab in request/ collection or have a look at the request in the Postman console and check `Set-Cookie` and `Authentication` headers) and edit the post accordingly.

Comment: You should never get this error since the `req.cookies` should be by default an empty object so the question is do you use [cookie-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies) ??

Comment: I had forgotten to add cookie parser. Thank you for pointing it out.